# How to select 3rd div which has specific css class

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="boxcontent">

<div>some content this div may be missing [dynamic genrated]</div>

<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
</div>

<div class="boxcontent">


<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
</div>


<div class="boxcontent">


<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

i found a problem that when i select them using css3 selector nth-child(3) then they select 2nd div in first .boxcontnent div.

when i say this last time they on point but never feel the problem i have here is the view :

http://jsfiddle.net/szz3C/1/

i want to select 3rd div or all boxcontent class div but in first box i found 2nd div select instead of third.

are their any sollution to solve this even using css3 or jQuery thanks for support if anyone can solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good "3rd of class" selector (or any other relational *class* based selector, they're all *sibling* based, including on type).

Your best alternative (given the example) here would be [`:nth-last-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo) which gets the `.box` `<div>` *if* it's the last-child in its parent, like this:

```
div.box:nth-last-child(1){ background-color:green; }
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/szz3C/2/).

Answer (score 6):

Try this CSS:

```
div:nth-of-type(3) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
.boxcontent .elem+.elem+.elem { /*3rd .elem*/ }
.boxcontent .elem+.elem+.elem+.elem { /*reset css if there are 4 .elem divs*/ }
```

there is also the `:last-child` selector

Comment: Be careful with `:last-child` it's buggier than `:nth-last-child()` in slightly older versions of Opera, Safari and Firefox...where as `:nth-last-child()` will just be ignored by them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use :last-child for everything but IE8 and below. Use Jquery to cover that?

```
$(".boxcontent:last-child").css({color:"red"});
```

But I wouldn't trust javascript to do anything important to the structure.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html